# How can we run a class

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I have one class that is sending emails to users. That class needs to execute after update a records. But the i am not receiving emails. Now i need check debugs of that class.

Comment: How the emails are sent? any workflow rule is used or any apex trigger after update? If its a code please paste the code and check the debug logs. Tere may be any issue with the code or if its a workflow rule, make sure you are hitting the conditions for the workflow rule to send the email. Need more details to get an answer from you.

Comment: or you should study about test classes.

Comment: Read this chapter of the documentation: [Invoking Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a method you should call it somewhere. Without seeing your code it's impossible to say how to do it in your case.

In general, if you want to execute some code after an update, you should use triggers. For example:

```
trigger TRIG_MyTrig on MyCustomObject__c (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            MyTrig_Handler.afterUpdate(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the handler(`MyTrig_Handler` in this case) you do all the required logic that should happen **after update**